# Как найти слово на странице HTML и если его нет на странице то выполнить функцию?

Tags: javascript

Как найти слово на странице HTML и если его нет на странице то выполнить мою функцию myfunction(), а если есть, то выполнить myfunction2() ? Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 0):

> Как найти слово на странице HTML и если его нет на странице то выполнить мою функцию myfunction(), а если есть, то выполнить myfunction2() ? Возможно ли это?

Вполне возможно...

Например таким образом. Только селектор `p` можно заменить на `body` или любой другой родительский элемент.

```js
const txt = document.querySelector('p').textContent
const re = new RegExp('Нейросеть', 'i')
if (re.test(txt)) myfunction2()
else myfunction()
//
function myfunction() {
  console.log('myfunction')
}
//
function myfunction2() {
  console.log('myfunction2')
}
```

```html
<p>Нейросеть пишет текст на русском языке онлайн с помощью алгоритмов машинного обучения по заданным ей ключевым словам.</p>
```

Comment: ksa, вижу код рабочий. Но у меня он никак не хочет работать.  И Body ставил, работает но как-то не так. А свой селектор         `<div class="guessme-gift"> Вася </div>`  писал так `document.querySelector('.guessme-gift')` Так вообще не работает. Вчём у меня может быть ошибка?

Comment: Функции у меня вот такие `var myfunction = function () {fs.Lock = true };
var myfunction2 = function () {fs.Lock = false };`

Comment: @User, чтобы ответить на твои вопросы нужно увидеть твой тестовый пример. Ты его можешь разместить в своем вопросе. Так будет более понятно с чем ты имеешь дело.